# JavaScript to paste form input in-line into body text

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form with input text fields which i would like to have pasted back into the HTML body resulting in a text string returned by a JavaScript function i.e. in the place where the input fields are sequentially. A simple example would be:

```
<html>
<body>
This is the first field <input type="text" id="first"/>
and this is the second <input type="text" id="second"/> one.
</body>
</html>
```

When i now view this page and enter ABC into field 1 and XYZ into field 2, i'd like to know how to use JavaScript to create a piece of text like so:

> This is the first field ABC and this is the second XYZ one.

So just to be clear, the web page itself need not change dynamically, i only want to be able to call the JavaScript function from elsewhere and then get the resulting text back with whatever is currently entered, pasted into the body text.
Any help much obliged.
Tiaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place form text and input fields into a div and call makeRecursive() (i.e. no args) to kick-start the text creation.

```
function makeRecursive(o)
{
    var b = o || document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    var t = "";
    if (b.nodeType === 1 && b.tagName === "INPUT")
        t += b.value;
    else if (b.nodeType === 3)
        t += b.nodeValue;
    if (b.hasChildNodes())
    {
        var c = b.firstChild;
        while (c)
        {
            t += makeRecursive(c);
            c = c.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM to loop through the child nodes of `body` (probably recursively), collecting the [`nodeValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080) properties of the [text nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) (those are the bits containing `"This is the first field "` and such) and, where you encounter an `input` [element](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614), getting its [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919) property instead. Build all of that text up into a string and you're there.

Some references:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

Comment: Thanks, my amateurish attempt yielded the result posted at the end.